# Pneumonia detection, using transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis

Im trying to increase the accuracy of my model, in order to predict x-ray images, and im working with a mobileNetv3, as my backbone model, as well, as using a customised CNN to make the prediction.
[my val_accurary is very volatile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqoNL.png)

how can i increase the accuracy/performance of my model, using this following architcture:[my model architcture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGxv7.png)